# Prove $(x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4)(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4)(x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4)$ is a symmetric polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The problem ask to prove what's in the title. From the book I know that, given the following polynomials,

$$h_1 = x_1x_2+x_3x_4$$
$$h_2 = x_1x_3+x_3x_4$$
$$h_3 = x_1x_4+x_2x_3$$

Any symmetric polynomial in $h_1, h_2$ and $h_3$ will be also symmetric in $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$. My idea is writing the polynomial $(x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4)(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4)(x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4)$ in terms of $h_1, h_2$ and $h_3$, but I haven't found an easy way to show that, and I've spend a lot of hours on it.

I feel this is the way since $h_1-h_2=(x_2-x_3)(x_1-x_4), \ h_1-h_3=(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_4), \ h_2-h_3=(x_1-x_2)(x_3-x_4)$ but when organizing the terms I can't get a way to get these products, also brute force and factorizing is really large.

Comment: If any swap of two variables preserves the form so does any permutation of the variables. (Easy exercise). And it's easy to see swaps don't change the form,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

I think it would simpler to check that the product is invariant by any transposition in $S_4$, since  transpositions  generate $S_4$. There are only $6$ of them.

*Example*: With the transposition $\tau=(1\,2)$
$$(x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4)(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4)(x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4)\to (x_2+x_1-x_3-x_4)(x_2-x_1+x_3-x_4)(x_2-x_1-x_3+x_4)= (x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4)\bigl[-(x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4)\bigr]\bigl[-(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4) \bigr],$$
which simply swaps the last two factors.

*Edit*: As pointed by @Edonbrayn in a comment, as $S_n$ is generated by the transpositions $(1\,k),\enspace k=2,\dots,n$, there remains only to check it is invariant by $(1\,3)$ and $(1\,4)$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've found a faster way. Since $S_4$ is generated by $\langle (1 2), (1 3), (1 4) \rangle$ you only have to proved it for these 3 transpositions.

Comment: Even faster: $S_4$ is generated by $(1 \ 2)$ and $(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4)$ ;-)